# $|i-(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)|^2=4\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2})$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-geometry

In the textbook Fuchsian Groups the author calculated what I believe to be $|i-(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)|^2=4\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2})$ then reduced it to $2-2\sin(\theta)$. I calculated using the sum of squares formula $\cos^2(\theta)+(1-\sin(\theta))^2=2-2\sin(\theta)$ by Pythagorean identity. But more important to me is how the author thought it was more direct to start from where they did, I mean what is the identity $1-\sin(\theta)=2\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2})$ called and why is that identity more natural then the sum of squares when finding the magnitude of the difference of two complex numbers on the unit circle?

Answer (score 1):

Use $|i-\exp(i\theta) |=|1-\exp(i\phi)|=|-2i\sin(\phi/2)|$ with $\phi:=\theta-\pi/2$. Each $=$ uses a phase shift.

Comment: Thank you, the first phase shift is by $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ last phase shift is by $-\frac{\phi}{2}$ .

Answer (score 0):

Let $-\cos\theta=r\cos t$

$r\sin t=1-\sin\theta$ where $r\ge0$ and $t$ is also real

Now $|r(\cos t+i\sin t)|=r|\cos t+i\sin t|=?$

Squaring and adding we get

$$r^2=(-\cos\theta)^2+(1-\sin\theta)^2=2(1-\sin\theta)$$

Now $\sin\theta=\cos(\pi/2-\theta)$

Use $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$